# jQM: Listview as form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know if it is possible to use listview as form?
Right now my list is something like this:

```
<form>
 <ul>
  <li name="answer" value=1 onClick="func()"><a name="answer" id=1 onClick="func()">Answer 1</a></li>
  <li name="answer" value=2 onClick="func()"><a name="answer" id=2 onClick="func()">Answer 2</a></li>
  ...
 </ul>
</form>
```

Or anyone have a nice idea for an optional solution, preferably something that looks like a listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-forms.html
and this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-forms-inset.html

Comment: Yay, I think you solved one of my older problems too. thanks again :)